# Get All Contents from Other Website with jQuery (Cross Domain)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to get the content from an element that is on other website. Then I want to display that content into another website that is on the same server.

I can get it with a YQL plugin and jQuery, but I can only get the content from some elements, not from all elements.

How can I get the content from all elements?

I was told that I have to use PHP to load all contents first, then show the results with jQuery. How to do it?

Comment: Never heard of it? Is it a plugin?

Comment: @DmitryB do not make fun of some one's ignorance...

Comment: I am sorry 3nigma ... you are right.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the option of using a server side language then you can make a proxy, have your proxy call that website and return the results to you in xml or the json format. make a php file call it proxy.php inside that file fetch data from cross domain

proxy.php

```
<?php
function get_url_contents($url){
        $crl = curl_init();
        $timeout = 5;
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        $ret = curl_exec($crl);
        curl_close($crl);
        return $ret;
}

    $url = “http://www.howtogeek.com”;
    $str = file_get_contents($url);

    echo $str;
?>
```

the client side

```
$.ajax({
 url:'proxy.php',
 dataType:'text\xml',
 success:function(data){//success handler
 //if the data is in xml format parse it using $.parseXML
 //do something
 },
 error:function(jxhr){ //error handler 
   console.log(jxhr.responseText);
 }
});
```

the above code is only for the demonstration purpose, i have taken help from [**here**](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/php-get-the-contents-of-a-web-page-rss-feed-or-xml-file-into-a-string-variable/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and let you know the result later

Comment: OK I've tried it. It doesn't return all contents. The result is the same as YQL, only some contents are acquired.